# how to toggle sub menus when user click one menu to other menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

when we click on menu C it open sub menus but when we click on B it closes C's sub menus but doesn't open B's sub menus (see fiddle)

```
    <div id="container" style="width: 250px;">
        <ul id="filter-menu-button-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>A</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>B</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1B</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1D</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1E</a>     
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open">  </span>C</a>
              <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">1A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1B</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1C</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1D</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1E</a>     
                   </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

jQuery code here

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
    "position": {
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top",
        collision: 'flipfit'
    }
});
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

if two menu B and C is present then click on one should open it's sub menu and close other submenu...how can we do this .
     check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/23/

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: could any body look into this?